# Find out current mailer class in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

In a "normal" ActionView I can find out the current controller with `controller_name`.

Is there any equivalent way to find out the mailer class in a mailer view?

Comment: just curious, why would you want to do that?

Comment: There's a conditional I want to run depending on type of mailer. I could as well pass some value to an instance variable in the mailer and check against that in the mailer view, but why not use existing information if its already there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, you can get the class of the mailer from the mailer view like this :

`self.controller.class.name`

You can use `self.action_name` to get the mailer method name